# How can I use LINQ to return the longest match of first part of a string?

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have the following object:

```
public struct Lookup {
    public string code;
    public string name;
}

public static List<Lookup> lookup =new List<Lookup>() {
    new Lookup {
        code = "12345",
        name = "abc"
    },
    new Lookup {
        code = "123",
        name = "def"
    },
    new Lookup {
        code = "123456",
        name = "ghi"
    }
};

public static Lookup FindMatch(string valueToSearchInLinq) {
    // Find the first result or null if no match found
    var result = lookup.FirstOrDefault( x => x );
    return result;
}
```

When running the following:

```
List<string> searchFor = new List<string>() { "123111117", "123456123", "12159785" };
foreach(var s in searchFor) {
   var r = FindMatch(s);
   if(r.code == null) {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("No match for {0}", s));
   } else {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( string.Format( "{0} is {1}", s, r.name ) );
   }
}
```

.. it should result in the following:

- 123111117 is def
- 123456123 is ghi
- No match for 12159785

I am having trouble with how to write the LINQ query on the line `var result = lookup.FirstOrDefault( x => x );` in the `FindMatch` method, to accomplish this goal.

Presently, I have this in a giant `for` loop with switch cases to check the length of the digits in decreasing order (for example, check "123456123", then "12345612", then "1234561" and so on) until a match is found. I would like to leverage the power of LINQ as I find its loops to process much faster than a conventional `foreach()`.

Comment: @keyboardP - the structure has been simplified to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Looks like you actually want `return lookup.Where(x => valueToSearchInLinq.Contains(x.code)).OrderByDescending(x => x.code.Length).FirstOrDefault();`  That or just keep the `lookup` ordered by the length of `code` and then just do the search for the first match in `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: `I find it's loops to process much faster than a conventional foreach()`  TIL

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft - That would be getting the longest string in general. What I wish to do is the inverse, get the object from a list which is the closest match, even if the match is a shorter length, I want the one that is longest that is most applicable as a match.

Comment: @juharr - that looks good.  Does `Contains` check only starting digits ? .  I apologize if that part wasn't clear, I wish to check from the start of the string always.  So  "012345111"  shouldn't match "12345"

Comment: @SanuelJackson No it would search for any substring match.  It sounds like you want `StartsWith` instead then.

Comment: Contains won't check only starting digits, but you could easily write a method that does -- I'd write one that returns the count of matching prefix characters in two strings (e.g. f("foo", "food") == 3, f("arby's", "aqueduct") == 1). If you've got enough items in your collection you may end up wanting a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), but that's not LINQ of course.

Comment: @juharr - correct.  I knew this old code could be rewritten in a nice one-liner that is light-years faster ^^ .  Havn't tested yet, but your solution looks solid to me   `return lookup.Where(x => valueToSearchInLinq.StartsWith(x.code)).OrderByDescending(x => x.code.Length).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Without seeing your code I can make no comment on if it will be more effecient.  However the best solution would be to make sure `lookup` is sorted so you don't have to do the `OrderByDescending`.

Comment: @SanuelJackson I think you might run into issues with your one liner for the `No match for 12159785 case`. It will probably throw a `NullReferenceException` at you when it gets to it.  
This is untested but I've used the `DefaultIfEmpty` to save myself from situations before if I really can't avoid them.
`lookup.Where(x => s.StartsWith(x.code)).OrderByDescending(x => x.code.Length).DefaultIfEmpty(new Lookup("NoMatch", "NoMatch")).FirstOrDefault().name`

Comment: @Timmy - you are correct, here is the final resulting linq string I am using (for future reference).  `var result=lookup.Where( x => valueToSearchInLinq.StartsWith( x.code ) ).OrderByDescending( x => x.code.Length ).DefaultIfEmpty(new Lookup()).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use LINQ to return the longest match of first part of a
>   string

As many comments suggested you could rely on *Matching* count. Since you want to match first part, I would suggest using `StartWith`.

```
public static Lookup FindMatch(string valueToSearchInLinq)
{
    // Find the first result or null if no match found
    var result = lookup.Select(x=> new {x, count = valueToSearchInLinq.StartsWith(x.code)? x.code.Length : -1})
                       .OrderByDescending(x=>x.count);

    // Check for any single match.
    return result.All(x=>x.count <0)? new Lookup() : result.First().x;
}
```

.

```
// Input
List<string> searchFor = new List<string>() { "123111117", "123456123", "12159785" };

// You get this output
123111117 is def
123456123 is ghi
No match for 12159785
```

One tip, there is an overloaded method which accepts comparison type, explore this option if you want to ignore case, etc...

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OxQs8R).